# Dynamically change image using Name Manager in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that has a dynamic number of rows. There is a specific column that changes the image based on the value of the cell next to it.

I have tried using this guide:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHBQ9Qxli3M

But it can only be used with a specific row and not dynamically.
I have tried using:

```
=INDIRECT("RC[-1]",0)
```

in my image's name but doesn't seem to change based on the targeted cell.

A link to my excel file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1v1RXhdPYU4j2CqxgNEWUtJ8gHbZV33xN

Comment: u need based on result or based on cell value

Comment: @MohammadAli How do you propose I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do this via VBA. You can place this code in the under 'Sheet1'. It detects when a change is made to column M, and then copies and pastes the image from your lookup table.

Note:

- it only works when the value 1 is inserted into the cell
- remove the '1' value deletes the image
- dragging down 1 values will not work (though the macro could be adjusted). Best to enter the '1' values one at a time ;)

---

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells, SelectedCells As Range, s As Shape
    Set KeyCells = Range("M13:M1000")
    Set SelectedCells = Range(Target.Address)

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, SelectedCells) Is Nothing Then
    'Place a 1 in the cell to insert an image
    If Application.Sum(Range(Target.Address)) = 1 Then        
      Sheets("Shapes").Shapes("Shape" & Range(Target.Address).Offset(0, -2).Value).Copy
      ActiveSheet.Paste
      Selection.Left = SelectedCells.Left
      Selection.Top = SelectedCells.Top
      SelectedCells.Select    
    Else 'Deletes the pictures if a 1 is not present
      For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If Not Intersect(SelectedCells, s.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then
            s.Delete
        End If
      Next s 
    End If
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: I need it to be draggable since my number of rows is dynamic.

Comment: I could take another next week. It shouldn't be too hard to adjust to make it draggable